# Redirect based on forged referrers

Tags: .htaccess

I think some malicious bot or user is forging the referrer in requests and thereby bypassing my deny from statements.

My htaccess has, among other snippets, the following

```
    ErrorDocument 403 "Nothing Interesting Here"
    order allow,deny
    deny from .eviluser.org
    allow from all
```

And I also have in my htaccess:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?eviluser.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

But my logs are showing:

```
    wnode1.eviluser.org - - [14/Nov/2012:18:21:44 -0500] "GET /some-document.html HTTP/1.0" 200 68584 "http://myoriginaldomain/some-document.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"
```

QUESTIONS:
1) how is it possible that wnode1.eviluser.org is even getting a 200 code if it has been denied?
2) Are they bypassing this by forging the referrer which is a document on my site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apache's [docs for mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) suggest that if you use a hostname in an `allow from` statement, it will do a reverse lookup. Nothing is mentioned for `deny from`, but I assume this works in the same way. [This blog post](http://betabug.ch/blogs/ch-athens/933) suggests the assumption is correct.

Given this, it shouldn't be possible to forge the originating hostname, at least for the `deny from` statement. The only way to do this would be to forge the originating IP address at the packet level, but there are [very limited situations](http://nmap.org/book/idlescan.html) where that can be useful. On the other hand, your `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` is obviously subject to forgery.

I'm not good enough with Apache configs to look at your code and see if there's a problem, but the above hints that it might be a misconfiguration rather than an Apache limitation.

I'd try denying based on IP address (e.g. `deny from 100.100.0.0`) to see if you'll get any better results. Have you tested out your own hostname, by the way? (e.g., `deny from localhost`), or tried denying a machine with a valid reverse lookup which you control?

Comment: I believe what's happening is the originating IP is being forged because despite having deny from the originating ip, they are still accessing the site.  I can succesfully deny access with a reverse lookup that I control.  Thank you for your help.